# How can I get oracle to add .5 instead of rounding off the number to 1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

**How can I get oracle to add .5 instead of rounding off the number to 1.**

> Scenario: I have a numeric field which calculates Sick days. However
>   if the employee takes half days, I want to see .5 instead of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set Precision and Scale for your number column or field . For example: 
Alter YourTable Modify ( YourColumn Number(3,1) )

This Definition Can hadel numbers like 4.5
Or number(4,2) that can store numbers like 4.05